# How to pull load balancing data from Google Cloud with API?

Tags: cloud, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

What is the best way to pull load balancing data from Google Cloud?

Answer (score 1):

The Google Cloud Load Balancer generates several kinds of data. There are usage reports, activity logs, and VPN logs. Then there are more generic Google Cloud services like exporting billing data.

[Usage reports](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/usage-export) can get sent to a Google Cloud Storage bucket of your choosing as a CSV file on a daily basis. You can retrieve files from GCS in a variety of ways, the easiest of which is to use the Google Cloud Console. Just click on the log to download it. You can also set up some sort of cron job from the command line using `gsutil`, or if you need a program to consume them, there are GCS libraries in a variety of languages.

[Activity Logs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/activity-logs) go through the [Stackdriver Logging service](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/). [VPN Logs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpn/logging) also go through Stackdriver Logging.

Billing data is [enabled from the console](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6293835?visit_id=1-636113693707975832-3824433610&rd=1) and is also periodically exported into a Google Cloud Storage bucket.

Comment: I can only find 4 metrics for loadbalancing https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics - am I looking in the right place?